# why return value is -1 in this sorted list [2, 3, 12, 100, 200] target value is 100?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search, selection-sort

I practice some selection sort and given a sorted list found a number with the binary search but is not working. Why output comes index -1.

```
  def selectionsort(lst, target):
      first = 0
      last = len(lst) - 1
      for step in range(len(lst)):
          min_idx = step
          for i in range(step + 1, len(lst)):
              min_idx = i
              if lst[min_idx] < lst[step]:
               #swap the elements
                  (lst[min_idx], lst[step]) = (lst[step], lst[min_idx])
          return -1
          while (first <= last):
              mid = (first + last) // 2
              if lst[mid] == target:
                 mid
              elif lst[mid] < target:
                 mid - 1
              else:
                 mid + 1
          return None

 def verify(index):
    if index is not None:
        print("Target found at index", index)
    else:
        print("Target not found")

data = [200, 12, 3, 100, 2]
result = selectionsort(data, 100)
verify(result)
print("The sorted list is \n", data)
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: There are indentation issues you should fix. This code cannot parse correctly because of that. It's a bit of a mess. Make it a habit to use a consistent indentation pattern, like 4 spaces, not the random amounts of indentation you have now.

Comment: indentation is not an issue actually I copy my code and just pasted it here. when i compile my code target found at index -1

Comment: Target found at index -1
The sorted list is 
 [2, 3, 12, 100, 200]

Comment: `some selection sort` I can sort of see that. `find a number with binary search` what effect do you expect code following a `return` to have?

Comment: *How* do you `compile` the code presented?

Comment: `I copy my code and just pasted it here` Try again "between the ~~~ *fences*". If it looks similar, it can't possibly pass without error messages. Try copying the code from your post to your test environment to make sure readers can reproduce your observations.

Comment: In the sorted list target at index 3 why is output at index -1

Comment: We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: Now I get `The sorted list is  
 [2, 200, 12, 100, 3]`

Comment: sorted list is [2, 3, 12, 100, 200]

Answer (score 0):

Your code was missing some return and variable assignments. Also binary search should be out of the loop. Also, return -1 shouldn't be there. Here is the fixed code.

```
def selectionsort(lst, target):
    first = 0
    last = len(lst) - 1
    for step in range(len(lst)-1):
        for i in range(step + 1, len(lst)):
            min_idx = i
            if lst[min_idx] < lst[step]:
                #swap the elements
                (lst[min_idx], lst[step]) = (lst[step], lst[min_idx])

    while (first <= last):
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        if lst[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif lst[mid] < target:
            first = mid + 1
        else:
            last = mid - 1
    return None

def verify(index):
    if index is not None:
        print("Target found at index", index)
    else:
        print("Target not found")

data = [200, 12, 3, 100, 2]
result = selectionsort(data, 100)
verify(result)
print("The sorted list is \n", data)
```